# ERROR: Package 'pyinstaller' requires a different Python: 3.12.0 not in '<3.11,>=3.7'

Tags: python

Im a little new to coding and i just got this error trying to run a file. what would i need to do to fix this problem?

It does Installing build dependecies ... done
getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done

A bunch of requirements was satishfied

Then it said

INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyinstaller to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Package 'pyinstaller' requires a different Python: 3.12.0 not in '<3.11,>=3.7'
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I'm a little lost on what to do so if someone could guide me into what to do to fix this error it'd be an amazing help

Comment: I think we need more information to determine the problem. Can you post the pip command or the file you were trying to run? Is this after a `pip install ...` or do you have a specific `pyproject.toml` that you can share?